# Previewing breakpoints in Adobe XD

Tags: responsive-design, prototype, preview

I am building a responsive prototype in Adobe XD but feel like I’m missing a trick. I have different artboards for different resolutions but how do I preview them in a single preview when I resize the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Adobe XD will not trigger switching to different artboards upon resizing the browser window. This is where its roots as a mobile app prototyping tool show through. You can submit a request for this feature at: https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007-adobe-xd-feature-requests